# Input type date calendar visible all the time

Tags: html, forms

Is it possible to have input type date calendar visible before you click on the input?

Comment: What code did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.input-container input {
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    padding: .75rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Thanks although you still have to click on the input to toggle the calendar.